# Where is "Create Influence" documented?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-2e, demon-the-descent

The phrase "Create Influence" shows up a few times like a noun in the text, however, I'm only able to find two references in the text to it, and those are using it. I'm assuming it's documented under a different name, where can I find out what "Create Influence" actually entails? (this is specifically quoted from p225 of GM, but appears to be the same in DtD)

> Causing the Condition: The Infrastructure Condition,
>   unlike Anchor and Resonant Conditions, is never naturally-
>   occurring. The God-Machine requires effort to prepare the way
>   for its angels: extended actions by cultists, unwitting pawns, or
>   even other angels to create Infrastructure. High-Rank angels
>   can use the Create Influence to instill this Condition on behalf
>   of themselves or a subordinate angel. In addition, characters
>   with the Destiny Merit are always subject to this Condition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No sooner do I post the question, than I scroll to the answer. p224 of GM

> •••• Create
>   The entity can create a new example of its sphere of influence;
>   creating a new anchor, instilling an
>   emotion, creating a new sapling or
>   young plant, creating a young animal
>   or brand new object. The entity can
>   cause a temporary Anchor, Infrastructure, or Resonant Condition
>   in a subject for the duration of the
>   Influence. The cost is four Essence.